# upload file reactjs err 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file-upload

When i am trying to upload file i have this error

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404".

I don't understand why. Here is my the piece of code.

```js
        import React, {Component}from 'react';
    import '../css/formLocation.css';
    import axios from 'axios'
    
    class FormLocation extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
          file : null
         }
      }
    
    
      handleClick9 = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({step9 : true})
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('images' , this.state.media)
      axios.post('http://localhost:1337/testmedias/', formData)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
      }  
    
      
      handleChangefile = e => {
      this.setState({
        media : e.target.files[0]
      })
      }
      
      render() { 
        return ( 
          <form>
          <div className='form' id='input' >
             
              <h6 className={this.state.step9? 'true': 'false'}>Ajoutez des images ?</h6>
              <input type='file' name='media' className='input' onChange={this.handleChangefile}/>
              <br/>
              <button onClick={this.handleClick9} >Soumettre</button>
          </div>
      </form>
         );
      }
    }
     

export default FormLocation;
```

I am using Strapi for the API. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code has a problem. It gives an error of 404 which means there is no API which you called.

Comment: yes there is an API. this is my API  [{"id":1,"created_at":"2020-03-30T17:40:24.948Z","updated_at":"2020-03-30T17:40:24.948Z","image":[{"id":2,"name":"Capture d’écran (36).png","hash":"5bb71f706ce443078eed99a46b1d7fb4","sha256":"gWCqYVBHw7ooa8GIOJFPckGI5Pny0V-D0hOKqgY0TPE","ext":".png","mime":"image/png","size":401.57,"url":"/uploads/5bb71f706ce443078eed99a46b1d7fb4.png","provider":"local","provider_metadata":null,"created_at":"2020-03-30T17:40:24.999Z","updated_at":"2020-03-30T17:40:24.999Z"}]}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
import React, {Component}from 'react';
    import '../css/formLocation.css';
    import axios from 'axios'

    class FormLocation extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
          file : null
         }
      }


      handleClick9 = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.setState({step9 : true})
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('images' , this.state.media)
      axios.post(`'http://localhost:1337/testmedias/'${formData}`)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
        })
      }  


      handleChangefile = e => {
      this.setState({
        media : e.target.files[0]
      })
      }

      render() { 
        return ( 
          <form>
          <div className='form' id='input' >

              <h6 className={this.state.step9? 'true': 'false'}>Ajoutez des images ?</h6>
              <input type='file' name='media' className='input' onChange={this.handleChangefile}/>
              <br/>
              <button onClick={this.handleClick9} >Soumettre</button>
          </div>
      </form>
         );
      }
    }


export default FormLocation;
```